# Regular expression matching two statements

Tags: regex

i have an input string as given below

```
 input=abc-chq-d26\mssq
```

Using this input string i have to match below statements

```
1.)dbs=abc-chq-d26\mssq;intsec=qwd2;usnme=abcd;pass=xxx
2.)dbs=abc-chq-d26;intsec=qwd2;usnme=abcd;pass=xxxx
```

I am able to match first  statement using below code.

```
dbs=abc-chq-d26\mssq;intsec=qwd2;usnme=abcd;pass=xxxx -match (.*)input(.*)
```

What pattern should i give to match the second statement also without changing the input and statement ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make `\mssq` optional by adding a `?`:

```
dbs=abc-chq-d26(\mssq)?;intsec=qwd2;usnme=abcd;pass=xxxx -match (.*)input(.*)
               ↑     ↑↑
```